# Getting values from generic foreign key in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model defined with a generic foreign key like this:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    request_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    request_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    request = GenericForeignKey('request_type', 'request_id')
```

When I grab the relations with a normal queryset it works fine.

```
statuses = Status.objects.all()
for status in statuses:
    print status.request.name
```

This prints all the names normally.

However I am using Django eztables which relies on grabbing the values like

```
statuses = Status.objects.all().values('request__name')
```

However when I try this I get:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'request' into field. Choices are: request_id, request_type, request_type_id
```

Is there a way to achieve this in Django?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

You must define your object with names like this:

```
class Status(BaseRequestStatus):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    ... more data
```

Then in the object you would like to filter on you must create a reverse generic relationship:

```
class Request(models.Model):
    statuses = GenericRelation(Status, related_query_name='request')
    ... other data
```

Then finally you can do fun stuff like

```
statuses = Status.objects.all().values('request__name')
```

or

```
Status.objects.filter(request__name__contains="stack overflow")
```

Comment: statuses = Status.objects.all().values('request__name') is returning other objects too, as None.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for [the contenttypes framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey):

> Due to the way `GenericForeignKey` is implemented, you cannot use such fields directly with filters (`filter()` and `exclude()`, for example) via the database API.

Since [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#values) is a part of this API and is listed just two sections below `filter()`/`exclude()` in the docs for [Aggregations and other QuerySet clauses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregations-and-other-queryset-clauses), my guess is that is why your approach fails.

I would recommend this instead:

```
status_list = Status.objects.all()
statuses = [{'request__name': status.request.name} for status in status_list]
```

Of course, the dict keys in the  list comprehension can be whatever you'd like. I left them as `'request__name'`, since that is what you would've gotten if your approach had worked properly.